# How to fetch value of input type = date using its id in C#

Tags: c#, html, sql

Trying to fetch value of date using its id

.aspx page code

```
<input type = "date" id = "idDate" class = "form-control">
```

I need this id to pass value of date to a sql backend column named 'colDate'
Since I have multiple inputs I am using ArrayList in C# to fetch values.

```
sarray.Add("@colDate," + idDate.SelectedValue)
```

Generally this is what is done for fetching values. But this code doesn't work for input type = date.

What is the possible solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not get its value by id, you should have a name attribute:

```
<input type = "date" id = "idDate" name = "idDate" class = "form-control">
-----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------------------------
```

Then you can get it like:

```
sarray.Add("@colDate," + Request.Form["idDate"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your markup:

```html
<input type = "date" id = "idDate" class = "form-control">
```

The input field value will be available in the incoming **Request** object. So, in order to access it, you can use the following code:

```
sarray.Add("@colDate," + Request.Form["idDate"]);
```

Hope this helps.